# Search and replace /'s in VI

Tags: linux, unix, shell

I was wondering how I would search and replace all /'s with -'s in vi.

%s///-/g doesn't work obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try escaping your /s, with a \.

`\/`. yes, it looks awful. That's how I remember it :P

Answer (score 11):

You can use any delimiter you wish, not just `/`. For example, `!`:

```
%s!/!-!g
```

This way, `/` becomes non-special and doesn't have to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

replacing separator is not always /.

Try

```
%s;hoge/hoge;fuga/fuga;g
```

in the text of "http://hoge/hoge"

Comment: that has already been said by ephemient